# I am not able to run the no right click botton in fancy box

Tags: fancybox

I am not able to run the fancy box helpers specifically the no right click button with another script i.e getting the fancybox to show the no. of images .the script runs like this..

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
      prevEffect : 'fade',
      nextEffect : 'fade',
      afterLoad : function() {
       this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length +          (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
      },
      helpers: {
       title: {
        type: 'inside'
       },
       thumbs: {
        width   : 50,
        height  : 50
          }
      }
     });
    });
    $(".fancybox")
        .attr('rel', 'images')
        .fancybox({
        beforeShow: function () {
            /* Disable right click */
            $.fancybox.wrap.bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
                    return false; 
            });
        }
    });    
</script>
```

When i run this script only the no. of images show and the no right click doesnot work.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I found disabling the right click works if I put the code inside the Ready function

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
            prevEffect: 'none',
            nextEffect: 'none',

            closeBtn: true,
            arrows: false,
            nextClick: true,

            padding: 10,

            beforeShow: function () {
                 /* Disable right click */
                 $.fancybox.wrap.bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
                 return false;
                 });
                },

                afterLoad: function () {
                  var alt = this.element.find('img').attr('alt');

                  this.inner.find('img').attr('alt', alt);

                  this.title = alt;
                },

            helpers: {
                title: {
                    type: 'inside'
                },
                thumbs: {
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50
                }

            }
        });

    });
```